# Доступ к измененному свойству родительского класса

Tags: php, ооп

Сразу извиняюсь за возможно тупой вопрос, только начинаю изучать ооп.

```html
class A {

  protected $age = 5;
  
  public function get() {
    $this->age = 10;
    
    $b = new B();
  }
}

class B extends A {
  public function __construct() {
    echo $this->age;
  }
}

$a = new A();
$a->get();
```

В методе get() класса A мы изменили свойство $age на 10, однако при вызове данное изменение игнорируется. При чем если использую статические свойства, все получается

Comment: у a и b разные age

Comment: а вопрос то в чём? И хотелось бы сразу уточнить, какие данные вы хотели увидеть?

Comment: статические переменные общие у всех инстансов,  а динамические - разумется - нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В главной программе создается объект класса `А`

для этого объекта по умолчанию установлено значение `age` равным `5`.

Далее в главной программе вызывается метод `get` класса `А`.

В методе `get` сначала присваивается новое значение в переменную `age` равное `10`.

(это значение далее НЕ используется).

Далее в методе `get` создается новый экземпляр класса `В`.

По умолчанию для нового экземпляра, так как он является наследником от класса `А`, инициализируется переменная `age` равным `5`.

В конструкторе класса `В` вызывается вывод `echo` текущего значения `age`. Выводится значение, установленное для экземпляра класса `В` равное `5`.

---

Если Вы хотите увидеть `10`, то нужно либо в конструкторе класса `В` присвоить нужное значение в переменную `age` до вызова `echo`, либо вызывать `echo` в методе `get` класса `А` после присвоения нужного значения.

Думаю, правильный код может выглядеть так:

```
class A {
  protected $age = 5;
  
  public function get() {
    echo $this->age;
  }
}

class B extends A {
  public function __construct() {
    $this->age = 10;
  }
}

$a = new A();
$a->get();
$b = new B();
$b->get();
```

На выходе будет
5
10